# minimize the area of convex hull of sum of 3 balls

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, lebesgue-measure

How should we place 3 balls $B_1,B_2,B_3$ on the plane, if we want to minimize the area of convex hull of $B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3$ ?

Balls can have boundary common points only -- the intersection of any two may be nonempty, but has to have empty interior.

Comment: Croft et al., *Unsolved Problems in Geometry*, 2012: "For $n\le56$, the best arrangements are **sausages**, that is, with the centers of the balls along a straight line, so that neighboring balls touch." https://books.google.com/books?id=rdDTBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA117&ots=7oCXcrFy3I&pg=PA117

Comment: Thanks for this link, but I'm interested in the case when balls doesn't have to be identical (only 3 balls interests me)

Comment: Oops, also I didn't realize your question was about disks in the plane, in which case the solution is to be "as hexagonal as possible". (I quoted the solution for the 3D case instead.)

Comment: but that thing is an interesting problem anyway, so don't delete your comment, even if it answers something different

Comment: Would not the answer be to put them in mutual contact? This would form a triangular shape with rounded corners (or a lop-sided sausage if the smallest ball fits in the convex hull of the other two). Moving any of the disks out of contact with the others would lengthen the sides of that "triangle", increasing the area.

Comment: A clarification here, please. I originally thought that by "on the plane" and "area" you meant them to be 2D balls: - i.e., disks. But now I am wondering, do you mean 3D balls sitting on top of a flat surface? And if so, do you mean "volume of the convex hull"?

Comment: Forgive me the names, if improper.
balls on the plane = 2D-balls being subsets on the plane (disks - I knew this word according to computers and UFO's only...), area = 2D Lebesgue measure (it is well-known that every convex set is measurable, so the question makes sense).